# Is there a limit regarding the number of files that are stored in the pg_wal directory?

Tags: postgresql, configuration, postgresql-13, wal

I am trying to find an explanation regarding the actual number of files that are being stored in my pg_wal directory.

I am using postgres v13 on a large DB with a lots of updates, inserts and deletes so I am expecting to have quite a lot of files in the pg_wal directory.

Based on what I have understood so far the number of files on the pg_wal directory depends on the `checkpoint_timeout` and the `max_wal_size` value. So which ever one hits first then the pg_wal directory is being rotated

I am experiencing though a weird behavior in my environment where I see constantly 7 pg_wal segments files. That means that I have 7*16MB = 112MB of files constantly.

Then I was looking at the files' timestamp to find out the oldest and the earliest and the below example shows that their timestamp is more than 5 mins. Oldest is 19:54 and newest is 20:05

```
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 10 20:04 000000010000E76A00000097
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 10 20:05 000000010000E76A00000098
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 10 20:10 000000010000E76A00000099
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 10 19:54 000000010000E76A0000009A
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 10 19:56 000000010000E76A0000009B
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 10 20:02 000000010000E76A0000009C
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 10 20:03 000000010000E76A0000009D
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 10 20:01 000000010000E76A0000009E
```

Trying to figure out why I am constantly having 7 pg_wal segment files.
My conf values are

```
checkpoint_timeout = 5min
max_wal_size = 2GB
```

I would count out that on that specific time there were 112MB of data that were changed because there are multiple scripts running on various moments and the number of files has never changed to something more or less.

I am investigating the way to create a replica and stubbed upon these values and trying to understand more things.

Tried to identify if the issue existed only on specific times of the day but that wasn't the case. Actually wherever I checked the pg_wal directory I would see 7 files.

The things that varied was the time between the oldest and the newest file. Sometimes it could be 10 minutes and other times it could be 30 or more (but this would depend on the actual data that are being written or changed in the DB)

Comment: Read [WAL Configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-configuration.html). In particular: *The server's checkpointer process automatically performs a checkpoint every so often. A checkpoint is begun every checkpoint_timeout seconds, or if max_wal_size is about to be exceeded, whichever comes first.*.  Which results in *Hence, after a checkpoint, WAL segments preceding the one containing the redo record are no longer needed and can be recycled or removed. (When WAL archiving is being done, the WAL segments must be archived before being recycled or removed.)*

Comment: Looks like this is more governed by `min_wal_size`. Why do you worry? Explaining the whole lifecycle of WAL in a SO answer is not easy...

Comment: I am asking and investigating that issue mainly to ensure that my system will have enough wal_segments for a replication process and won't go out of sync.

I know that I can use the `wal_keep_size` variable for that reason but wanted to understand even more my current situation.

@AdrianKlaver thank you for your comment. I have read the WAL Configuration documentation and that sentence but I still can't understand why there are constantly 7 files. Not more, not less

Comment: 1) Because that is the right balance for the load your server is seeing. As @LaurenzAlbe said WAL sizing is involved. Basically though it is a circular process where old WAL files are recycled into new ones. If there is steady state of changes then the files will reach a steady state also. 2) You want to take a look at {Replication slots](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION-SLOTS).

Comment: I will look into the replication slots as well. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about the number of WAL segments in `pg_wal` if you plan to build a standby server. All you have to do is to configure PostgreSQL so that it retains enough WAL for the standby server. There are three ways to do that:

1. Set `wal_keep_size` on the primary, so that it always retains a certain amount of old WAL.
2. Set `archive_mode = on` and configure `archive_command` so that PostgreSQL creates a WAL archive. Then set `restore_command` on the standby so that it can recover from the archive. You can use `archive_cleanup_command` on the standby to delete archived WAL segments that are no longer needed.
3. Use a replication slot that makes the primary retain just the right amount of WAL.

I recommend options 2 or 3.

Comment: Thank you @laurenz-albe for your help. I have even saw your other responses for example in [that question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/303868/postgresql-increase-wal-retention-to-avoid-slave-go-out-of-sync-with-master) and it was really helpful. I am planning to use the first option as I find it the one with the less configuration to be done.

 I was asking to understand in more depth the issue

Comment: As I said, that is out of scope for a Stackoverflow answer. WAL segment management cannot be explained in a paragraph or two.